# spring contract cloud AutoConfigureStubRunner

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

In my spring cloud contract test I have already some remote stubs like after I followed the spring cloud contract docs https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/2.0.x/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_stub_runner.html

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(repositoryRoot = StubRunnerRepositoryRoot.URL, stubsMode = 
    StubsMode.REMOTE, ids = {
 "uk.co.blah.service:blah-service:+:stubs"...})
```

However, I would also like to have some local stubs

```
   stubsMode = StubsMode.LOCAL
```

So basically having some remote stubs and some local ones? Is that possible? Having multiple AutoConfigureStubRunner? It doesn't seem to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do local only, you need to ensure that you have them in your local m2. It will be enough for you to add that stubs JAR as a dependency in your project and it will be downloaded to your local .m2 upon building of the project. Then you can use `LOCAL` and it will work cause you have just downloaded the jar.